# TEI-XML dictionary to simple HTML table using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, tei

Need to put "entryFree" words in a first column (leaving `<form>` content for second), and "sense" and other as a second, every pair in the same row, with borders. Sample XSL stylesheet contains formatting only.

sample XML: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sNAbWw5xo1pgwK2QfQwPrbZtZt8uV48T/view?usp=sharing

fancy XSL (licence permits modification): https://github.com/michmech/tei-dictionary.xsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map all `entryFree` elements to HTML table rows (i.e. HTML `tr` elements in an HTML `table`) then set up the `table` as needed and in a `tbody` process all `entryFree` elements, mapping them with a template to a `tr`:

```
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Table</h1>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>free entry</th>
                        <th>forms/senses</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:entryFree"/>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:entryFree">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@sortKey"/>
        </td>
        <td>
           <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

You will need to remove the template matching `tei:entryFree` obviously.

As for formatting the table, that is a HTML/CSS problem, HTML 4 https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.1 allows e.g.

```
            <table rules="all" frame="border">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>free entry</th>
                        <th>forms/senses</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:entryFree"/>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

in HTML5 I think using CSS is preferred:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
            <style>
                table.dict { 
                  border: 1px solid black;
                  border-collapse: collapse;
                }
                table.dict th, table.dict td {
                  border: 1px solid black;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Table</h1>
            <table class="dict">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>free entry</th>
                        <th>forms/senses</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:entryFree"/>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```